# Ruby // Selecting and Transferring items from hashes using Input

Tags: ruby, methods, hash

I am making a basic CLI web **scraper** using Ruby.  The user will be asked which stock index they would like to see.  Their input will be taken as:

`$input = gets.chomp.downcase.to_s`

I have a hash that I am using as a makeshift database.  Not the best practice, I know, but it's the best thing I have come up with only using Ruby objects.

Example hash:

```
index_info_resource = {
   "dax" => {
      full_name:  "Deutscher Aktienindex (German stock index)",
      exchange:   "Frankfurt Stock Exchange"
      web_site:   "investing.com/dax/test
   },
   "fchi" => {
      full_name:  "Cotation Assistée en Continu",
      exchange:   "Euronext Paris"
      web_site:   "investing.com/fchi/test
   }
}
```

Because there will be a **scraper** class, information will coming from there as well as from this db hash, I was thinking to make a staging hash: `@@requested_index = Hash.new` where I would then add the information I need like so:

`@@requested_index[:full_name] = index_info_resource["#{"dax"}"][:full_name]`

***My problem is*** when I use the users input in this way:

`@@requested_index[:exchange] = index_info_resource["#{"$input"}"][:full_name]`

I get this error:

`` undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ``

I am not sure why or how to fix this.  If I use just an identical string, it works.  If the user's input is that same string, it does not.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Take a look at `YAML::Store` which is a built in way to persist a hash to file https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$input` is already a string therefore you do not need string interpolation in this case. Additionally `"#{"$input"}"` will evaluate to `"$input"` not the value of that variable.

Just change

```
@@requested_index[:exchange] = index_info_resource["#{"$input"}"][:full_name]
```

to

```
@@requested_index[:exchange] = index_info_resource[$input][:full_name]
```

Comment: I tried that / just tried again.  It still give me: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: When I put ` test = "dax" ` above `@@requested_index[:exchange] = index_info_resource[test][:full_name]` it works.  But if I set `test = $input` it no longer works again, and I get the same error.  Would there be a reason why `$input` can not be seen?

Comment: What is the output when you call `puts $input.inspect` right above that?

Comment: When I enter dax into the command line it outputs:
=> "dax"
Also, when I do `puts $input.class`, I get:
=> String
I feel like for some reason, the new hash can not 'see' the variable.  Would there be another way of writing this to avoid such an error?  Thank you for your help.